# Java + Django web service?

Tags: java, django, json

I am trying to start with development of java client + django web service.

There are few questions that are bothering me :

1) I would use gson lib for java, is there any de-serializer for django that is gson alike?

2) How POST mechanism is working with JSON ? I would use Apache, what is needed so I can make POST and how in general can you POST JSON ?

3) What is procedure for serverside django to catch JSON that is being POST-ed?

4) How does serverside service returns JSON to client?

5) (most confusing) How does auth methods work with all of the above?

Please don't respose with google it because I have google it around and I am still confused with some basic concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There are plenty of good python json libraries. The best ones are fairly simple. django actually HAS one  built in, though I can't remember the name.  something like django.json.
2. you can POST and GET json by simply passing it in as a parameter in the request.
3. A servlet that recognizes the json input parameter, gets the JSON and deserializes it for consumption by the server.
4. write the JSON to the response as a name/value parameter pair.
5. I don't have a good answer for this. Not sure I entirely understand what you are looking for.

Comment: First tnx for help!

What does it mean to pass as paramter?. Does return means that it will return it simply like html but json syntax?.

Comment: so a parameter is a name/value pair in the http request. you can set the name to be something interesting like json_input, and have the json formatted data as the value. Then you have access to it in your servlet. conversely pack it into the response the same way and play with it in javascript as needed.